# Wordpress custom database query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to get the result from the database with the mysql LIKE but in wordpress its not working here is the code of what i am trying

```
//this is what i am putting in where clause.
$state = $_POST['state'];
//table name.
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'userprofile';
//trying but this is returning empty
$q = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $table_name . 'WHERE state LIKE \'%' . esc_sql( like_escape( $state ) ) . '%\'';
echo $q;
$result = $wpdb->get_results($q);
if (empty($result)) {
    echo "the result is empty";
}
//returns empty array.
print_r($result);
```

Comment: i think you are missing an open quote `'` before the opening `%`

Comment: `"$_POST['state']"` is cargo-cult programming. the `"` are totally unecessary when doing a simple copy-a-variable, and if you INSIST on using `"` then you CAN'T have the `'` on the array keys.

Comment: @marc B okay i get it but the results is still empty..
and what if its empty it still show the same empty array.

Answer (score 1):

Like Marc B. said, there are some missing quotes and unnecessary quotations.. change your query line, to this:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM $table_name
      WHERE state LIKE '%". esc_sql( like_escape( $state ) ) . "%'
      AND WHERE city LIKE '%". esc_sql( like_escape( $city ) ) . "%'
      AND WHERE session LIKE '%". esc_sql( like_escape( $session ) ) . "%'
      OR WHERE another LIKE '%". esc_sql( like_escape( $another ) ) . "%' ";
```

and your POST line to this:

```
$state = $_POST['state'];
```

Comment: and how does changing the string construction method chang anything?

Comment: thanks the query worked and could you please guide me if i were to use 2 more where clauses etc "city and session". where will those things go in the query and i want to use OR in them. can you please update your answer. thanks

Comment: No problem. there you go

Comment: @CodeGodie They all have to use the same like situation. i am too much puzzled with the quotes right now would you please help. i tried to replicate the like statement but again it returned an empty array

Comment: there you go.. It would be easier if you use a better IDE. How do you code? what IDE do you use?

Comment: @CodeGodie i am using sublime text 2 right now. and the query is generating again an empty array i just copies your code and it returns an empty array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81909/discussion-between-codegodie-and-zohaib).

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a space:

```
$q = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $table_name . 'WHERE[..snip..]
                                       ^---here
```

which means you're producing

```
SELECT * FROM whateveruserprofileWHERE
```

which is invalid SQL.

Answer (score 0):

do this way

$state = esc_sql( $state );

$state = like_escape( $state );

$state = '%' . $state . '%';

$q = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $table_name . 'WHERE state LIKE  '$state';